# Feign configuration not being used

Tags: java, spring-boot, feign

I am using Feign in a Spring Boot API and I would like to configure it using the following:

```
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.auth.BasicAuthRequestInterceptor;
import feign.codec.ErrorDecoder;
import feign.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class FeignClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
        return new ErrorDecoder.Default();
    }

    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient client() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate -> {
            requestTemplate.header("user", "some user");
            requestTemplate.header("password", "some password");
            requestTemplate.header("Accept", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());
        };
    }


}
```

Problem is that if I use the following code in a service I get a 401, seems like no authentication data was provided:

```
        Feign.builder()
        .client(new OkHttpClient())
        .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
        .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
        .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Npa.class))
        .target(AClass.class, "https://some.website");
```

If I just add one line specifying user and password it works:

```
    Feign.builder()
    .client(new OkHttpClient())
    .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
    .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
    .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Npa.class))
    .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("some user", "some password"))
    .target(AClass.class, "https://some.website");
```

I would prefer to use the configuration but I cannot understand what is wrong in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've created some beans then you don't need to instantiate them again manually in builder steps.

The pseudo-class where you can create your feign client could be like this:

```
@Component
public class FeignClientFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ErrorDecoder errorDecoder;

    @Autowired
    private OkHttpClient client;

    @Autowired
    private RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    public AClass getFeignClient() {
        return Feign.builder()
                .client(client)
                .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Npa.class))
                .requestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .target(AClass.class, "https://some.website");
    }
}
```

Of course, there is a lot of options to improve it. F.e., you can create other beans (for encoders, loggers and so on) or use the default (autoconfigured) ones.

Or you can do it in `@Configuration` class if you need only one feign client bean.

In case of request interceptors - there is another builder step `.requestInterceptors`, where you can pass a collection of them.

**EDIT:** For basic authentication you don't need to have separate username and password headers but one header "Authorization" instead. Its value should look like "Basic username:password" where "username:password" part should be encoded with Base64 ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)).

So, in your `@Configuration` class you can write smth like this:

```
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
    return requestTemplate -> {
        String encodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder()
            .encodeToString("some user:some password".getBytes());
        requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
        requestTemplate.header("Accept", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());
    };
}
```

Then you can use this bean for building Feign client as I described above.

**Another option:** Because the creation of authorization header is a pretty common task, the `BasicAuthRequestInterceptor` was introduced by Feign which does the same. You can use it instead. So now, in `@Configuration` class you can create two beans:

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("basicAuthRequestInterceptor")
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor() {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("some user","some password");
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("customRequestInterceptor")
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        return requestTemplate -> {
            requestTemplate.header("Accept", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType());
        };
    }
```

In this case, you need to modify the feign client building method in order to apply both these interceptors:

```
@Component
public class FeignClientFactory {

    @Autowired
    private ErrorDecoder errorDecoder;

    @Autowired
    private OkHttpClient client;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("basicAuthRequestInterceptor")
    private RequestInterceptor basicAuthRequestInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customRequestInterceptor")
    private RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    public AClass getFeignClient() {
        List<RequestInterceptor> requestInterceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        requestInterceptors.add(basicAuthRequestInterceptor);
        requestInterceptors.add(requestInterceptor);

        return Feign.builder()
                .client(client)
                .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
                .decoder(new GsonDecoder())
                .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Npa.class))
                .requestInterceptors(requestInterceptors)
                .target(AClass.class, "https://some.website");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Is it ok to do dependency injection using properties? Should I maybe use a constructor?

Comment: I applied the change as suggested but error remained the same.

Comment: Aww, missed that. In your custom interceptor you're trying to pass username and password in two separate headers. But in case of basic auth, you need to create one header "Authorization", which value would be like "Basic user:pass", where "user:pass" part is encoded in base 64 ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)). If you want, you can repeat the logic from [here](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/auth/BasicAuthRequestInterceptor.java#L51) or do it yourself.

Comment: About field injection - I did it just for example, ofc it's possible to do it via constructor or setters.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood...
Would you mind updating your answer?

Comment: Issue remains identical. This is driving me nuts... Adding just a single .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("some user", "some password")) to the feign builder works, adding the SAME to the configuration not. I have no clue.

Comment: Really strange. Is it possible to share the project on github, e.g.? Maybe we're missing smth.

Comment: I will arrange a minimal example and upload it. On the other hand did you test the code you posted or just wrote it without running it?

Comment: I took it from the real project (renamed some things but the overall idea is the same)